# How to unwrap element using jQuery 1.3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

```
<div class="photo">
 <a href="#"><img src="/media/image.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Using `unwrap()` is awesome, but right now I have to unwrap the `img` above using an older version of jQuery, removing the link and retaining just the image inside of the `div`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try setting html of div, also the closing `/` of img tag is missing.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5VpD6/1/)**

```
$('.photo').html($('.photo a').html())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.photo a').replaceWith($('.photo a').html());
```

[Working Example: Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3kKj/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to place the contents along with the associated data/events etc then

```
$('.photo a').each(function(){
    $(this).after($(this).contents());
    $(this).remove()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aWQSj/) or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aWQSj/2/)